# SQL Pivot Query for Attendance Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have below query written for my attendance report. everything works fine except one thing. i have multiple checkin/checkout allowed in a day in my application now when i run my query it returns checkin, checkout, total, checkin checkout total. the result i expect is something like: checkin, checkout, checkin, checkout.... total.

Below is the query:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Employee, [2016-09-01],[2016-09-02],[2016-09-05],[2016-09-06],[2016-09-07],[2016-09-08],[2016-09-09] from 
              (
                  SELECT src.EmployeeID, isnull(b.EmployeeName,'') +' '+ isnull(b.LastName,'')  Employee
                        ,[CheckinDate]
                        , ISNULL(CAST(c.LeaveDesc as VARCHAR(max)), STUFF((
                        SELECT ', ' + CAST(ISNULL(CheckinTime,'') AS VARCHAR(5))  + char(10) + CAST(ISNULL(CheckoutTime,'') AS VARCHAR(5)) + 
                        char(10) + CAST(ISNULL(TotalHours,'') AS VARCHAR(5))
                        FROM EmployeeDetail
                        WHERE (EmployeeID = src.EmployeeID and CheckinDate = src.CheckinDate) 
                        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
                        ,1,2,'')) AS Result
                        FROM [EmployeeDetail] as src inner join EmployeeMaster b on src.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID and src.KindergardenID = b.KindergardenID  
                        left outer join leavetype c on src.leaveid = c.leaveid 
                        WHERE  src.KindergardenID = 1
                        GROUP BY src.EmployeeID, isnull(b.EmployeeName,'') +' '+ isnull(b.LastName,''), CheckinDate,LeaveDesc
             ) x
              pivot 
              (
                   max(Result)
                  for CheckinDate in ([2016-09-01],[2016-09-02],[2016-09-05],[2016-09-06],[2016-09-07],[2016-09-08],[2016-09-09])
              ) p
```

Any help in changing the query to make it work as expected is appreciated.
Let me know if i was confusing in asking.

Comment: microsoft sql server 2012.

Comment: Please, provide some data sample on input, your query results you are getting now and what output you actually want to get.

Comment: Can you provide input and output sample data?

Comment: u hv done 2nd step.you missing first step.using CTE first make query where you deal with check-in,check-out and give you desire result.then using CTE,make the query pivot.i think this query will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Employee, ' + @cols + ' from 
              (
                  SELECT src.EmployeeID, isnull(b.EmployeeName,'''') +'' ''+ isnull(b.LastName,'''')  Employee
                        ,[CheckinDate]
                        , ISNULL(CAST(c.LeaveDesc as VARCHAR(max)), isnull(left(convert(time,DATEADD(minute,(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ''0:00:00'', TotalHours))),0)),5),''N/A'') + char(10) + STUFF((
                        SELECT '', '' + CAST(ISNULL(CheckinTime,'''') AS VARCHAR(5))  + ''-'' + CAST(ISNULL(CheckoutTime,'''') AS VARCHAR(5)) + 
                        char(10) 
                        FROM EmployeeDetail
                        WHERE (EmployeeID = src.EmployeeID and CheckinDate = src.CheckinDate) 
                        FOR XML PATH(''''),TYPE).value(''(./text())[1]'',''VARCHAR(MAX)'')
                        ,1,2,'''')) AS Result
                        FROM [EmployeeDetail] as src inner join EmployeeMaster b on src.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID and src.KindergardenID = b.KindergardenID  
                        left outer join leavetype c on src.leaveid = c.leaveid 
                        WHERE  src.KindergardenID = ' + CAST(@kindergardenid as varchar(max)) + '
                        GROUP BY src.EmployeeID, isnull(b.EmployeeName,'''') +'' ''+ isnull(b.LastName,''''), CheckinDate,LeaveDesc
             ) x
              pivot 
              (
                   max(Result)
                  for CheckinDate in (' + @cols + ')
              ) p
```